# twitter segue transition issue in iOS app

Tags: ios, twitter, xcode5

I am integrating Twitter app in my iOS app. The problem is after successful login, the segue that  should take the control to the specific view controller, return back to my login page and not to the desired view controller. The segue has been performed and i can see that in my output console. Also the wired thing is when i click the tweet button on login page, the segue performed second time visually at last.

My twitter login method is as follow:

```
 - (IBAction)tweetbutton:(id)sender {

     [SCTwitter initWithConsumerKey:@"your_consumer_key" consumerSecret:@"your_consumer_secret"];    
     [SCTwitter loginViewControler:self callback:^(BOOL success){
                 NSLog(@"Login is Success -  %i", success);
                 if (success) {
                    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"authentication" sender:self];
                 }
      }];
 }

 -(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{

   NSLog(@"prepareForSegue: %@", segue.identifier);
 }
```

The output in console is:

> ```
> 2014-12-10 23:54:16.923 gems[1300:60b] Login is Success -  1
> 2014-12-10 23:54:16.946 gems[1300:60b] prepareForSegue: authentication
> ```

I don't understand where I am wrong and  why segue is not performing automatically visually on login success. Please suggest a suitable solution so that direct automatic transition to specific view controller without getting back on Login page again and also for your knowledge I am using plain view controller and not navigation controller.

Thanks in advance. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try using only the performSegueWithIdentifier line in tweetbutton method. Remove all others and check whether its navigating to next view or not.

Comment: I doubt that you have connected the segue for button click and plus you are  manually also redirecting to that screen by code ...

Comment: Agreed @Leena, that's why I asked to check whether navigation is working or not. If its not then problem is in storyboard connections.

Comment: thank you for the reply guys. i considerd your suggestions.as per mrunal says, segue performed on button click removing everything else. but i want segue is performed in a flow after successful login.so i doubt if something is wrong in the position of segue in tweet button. so please tell me the right place to perform segue and also i am using SCTwitter and twitter+oauth framework. and please guys read my post carefully again. because u guys misunderstand my problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Using Swift 3:**

Use this in **viewDidLoad()**:

```
Twitter.sharedInstance().logIn { (session, error) in
            if error == nil {
                performSegue(withIdentifier: "authentication", sender: self)
            }
        }
```